# Appium - running test on two physical devices

Tags: java, node.js, selenium, appium

I have seen many threads with this question but I can not seem to find a good answer. They all say to start two appium servers, sync up the devices to two different ports and then run it. This however does not seem to work for me. Heres what I do..

1. Open two node.js terminals
2. Start two appium servers using the folliwing command  :  node appium.js -p 4476 -U      &      node appium.js -p 4475 -U one for each appium server
3. I see that Appium has started with a REST http interface at 0.0.0.0:(port #) for both servers.
4. Run my test from my testng file.

   ```
   <test name="Test 1">
       <parameter name="deviceName" value=""/>
       <parameter name="platformName" value="Android"/>
       <parameter name="browserName" value="Chrome"/>
       <parameter name="local" value="appium"/>
       <parameter name="baseUrl" value="https://mtest.com/"/>
       <parameter name="bsAccount" value="http://0.0.0.0:4476/wd/hub"/>
       <classes>
           <class name="com.testsuites.regression.Smoke"/>
       </classes>
   </test>

   <test name="Regression">
       <parameter name="deviceName" value=""/>
       <parameter name="platformName" value="Android"/>
       <parameter name="browserName" value="Chrome"/>
       <parameter name="local" value="appium"/>
       <parameter name="baseUrl" value="https://mtest.com/"/>
       <parameter name="bsAccount" value="http://0.0.0.0:4475/wd/hub"/>
       <classes>
           <class name="com.testsuites.regression.Regression"/>
       </classes>
   </test>
   ```

Yes I have put the corresponding UDID into the deviceName param. I am doing this through intellij, running windows 7. Thanks for any help!

Comment: are you using Selenium Grid?

Comment: Are appium servers running fine and you are getting issues while running your test ? Can you copy paste the error ?

Comment: @LiamFerris no, I am not using the Grid, could that be why?

Comment: I'll add an answer of how to use grid for to allow testing on multiple devices

Comment: @LiamFerris That would be so great, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Selenium Grid

Selenium Grid was built to allow multiple selenium sessions to be ran and handled automatically. It is configurable for multiple devices (when used in conjunction with appium), allows for parallel or standard testing and allows you to create nodes for each device based on a capability system.

**Hub**

Selenium Grid hub is a central server which manages the ability to run multiple tests.

1. [Download the Selenium Standalone Server](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/)
2. Run the following to start the hub:

   ```
   $java -jar path/to/selenium-server-standalone-X.X.X.jar -role hub -port 4444
   ```

**Node**

1. [Install node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/)
2. Install appium (unless you already have)

   ```
   $npm install –g appium
   ```
3. You will need a JSON file for each node, which outlines the capabilities of the device (or devices) that this node is to be used for:

---

```
{
"capabilities":
[
{
"browserName": "Chrome",
"deviceName": "deviceName",
"device": "device",
"udid":"XXXXXXXX",
"version":"X.X.X",
"maxInstances": 5,
"platform":"ANDROID",
"platformName": "Android"
}
],
"configuration":
{
"cleanUpCycle":2000,
"timeout":10000,
"proxy": "org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy", 
"url":"http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub",
"maxSession": 5,
"port": 4723,
"host": "0.0.0.0",
"register": true,
"registerCycle": 5000,
"hubPort": 4444,
"hubHost": "localhost"
}
}
```

Keep in mind each node needs to use a different port for the `url` and `port` configurations. 4723, for example.

4. Create a node

   ```
   $appium --nodeconfig /Path/To/Config.json -p 4723 -bp 5723 --chromedriver-port 6723
   ```

Each node needs three unique ports (Port, Bootstrap Port, ChromeDriver Port) and the port specified with `-p` I found needs to be the same as the port given in the config.

**Testing**

I would recommend using a testing framework such as TestNG or JUnit, which will allow you to run test suites and pass capabilities in `@BeforeClass` methods etc.

But essentially all you need to do is create a AndroidDriver using capabilities identical to those specified in your JSON config file for a certain node and then that instance of AndroidDriver will be associated with that specific node (Selenium Grid handles this) and furthermore with the device which the node is associated with. It's very simple really, once you know what you are doing!

Initialise AndroidDriver like this:

```
driver.set(new AndroidDriver(new URL(SELENIUM_HUB_URL),
                capabilities));
```

A common mistake people make is passing the AndroidDriver the node URL instead of the Hub URL (`http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub` instead of `http://0.0.0.0:4444/wd/hub`) this is really common because it will, at least initially work, but then when trying to use any Selenium Grid specific functionality (such as multiple devices) everything will break.

Good luck and I hope this helps,

Liam

Comment: Thank you so much for taking time to post this.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Selenium Grid to do it on several devices. But you should be able to do it without SG too. Maybe you miss some parameters when launching Appium node. I use following:

`node appium -p <port> --udid <UDID> -bp <bootstrap_port>`

Comment: I see alot of posts talk about the bootstrap port and I feel that may be the solution.. What is the bootstrap port and how would I define one?

Comment: I actually have not investigated its meaning completely. Just put some port which differs from other ports and bootstrap ports used. Works for me.